# C# WPF RichTextBox Scroll to text?

Tags: c#, wpf, text, textbox

I'm working on alittle writing game and I encountered a problem. I have a richtextbox which contains one paragraph with alot of runs in it, and I want it to scroll to some run i have. I have a List object which contains all the inlines in the RTB, and the Select() Method doesn't work for some reason, maybe because it's a ready-only rtb. Any ideas for a way to scroll to selected word?
My Code:

```
    private bool isKey = false;
    private Paragraph p;
    private List<Inline> inlineList;
    private int inlineIndex = 0, wpm = 0, wordIndex = 0, lineIndex = 0;
    private string[] words;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        p = new Paragraph();
        foreach (string s in words)
        {
            p.Inlines.Add(s);
            p.Inlines.Add(" ");
        }
        WordBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();
        WordBox.Document.Blocks.Add(p);
        inlineList = p.Inlines.ToList();
        inlineList[0].Background = Brushes.LightGray;
        this.Activate();
        InputBox.Focus();
    }
    //The Method I want to put the scrolling feature in:
    private void MoveWord()
    {
        if (inlineIndex + 2 < inlineList.Count)
        {
            inlineList[inlineIndex].Background = Brushes.Transparent;
            inlineIndex += 2;
            inlineList[inlineIndex].Background = Brushes.LightGray;
            WordBox.Selection.Select(inlineList[inlineIndex].ContentStart, inlineList[inlineIndex].ContentEnd);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show(wpm.ToString());
    }
```

For Example:
the rtb contains:
Hey Hello what's up
word schnitzel hey

And I want it to scroll to the word "hey".

I've tried to use Select() method, which didn't work...

Comment: Show us your code, and some example text, and the place where you want it to scroll to.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I edited :)

Comment: Where is your `Select()` call?

Comment: @RobertHarvey select didn't work for me so I found a different way to paint a selected word. I have a List<Inlines> and I know the index of each word, so I just change the background and foreground property of each. I don't know why select didn't work, it didn't have any effect on scrolling/color of my text.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.  Judging from your example text, I'd say that one possible problem might be that the Select() is case-insensitive (it's catching the first "Hey")..  No way to really know without seeing how you're calling Select().

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've edited MoveWord() method with my select() attempt, I hope you can tell me what the problem is. Anyway thank you very much for helping me so far! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69622/discussion-between-sword-art-and-robert-harvey).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create runs and add runs (not inlines)
Save a reference to the runs (e.g. a List)
And then just call Runs[x].BringIntoView()
Have not tested on RTB but I have done this with FlowDocument and FlowDocumentViewer

[BringIntoView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598110(v=vs.110).aspx)